# Flip bitmap in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, bitmap

I have a `Bitmap` object that I need to sometimes flip horizontally, sometimes vertically, sometimes both.  The full framework has the `Image.RotateFlip()` method which is exactly what I need.  Unfortunately like most useful features on the full framework, this method does not exist on the compact framework.  Is there a simple way to do this?  The best I could find was [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ImageRotationForCF.aspx), but it uses unsafe code which I'd like to avoid and it could only do rotation not flipping.

Edit: Ok, I found a way to do some optimizations where I only need to do a vertical flip.

Comment: Jason, that same link uses a "safe" method to rotate. It says it took nearly 3 minutes to complete a 90deg rotation on a 800x600 pixel image which seems way too long to me. i would try it on your device to see how it performs and perhaps look for a bottle neck. In my experience the get and set pixel methods are quite fast. Also, it's only a tiny step in logic from rotation to flipping...

Comment: Why avoid unsafe code?  It's fast, it works, and it's completely legal in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CF doesn't support it, but if your device supports the Imaging Library, then you can P/Invoke down to [IBasicBitmapOps::Flip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915480.aspx). The [SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/cf/products/sdf.ocf) already has this wrapped in the [OpenNETCF.Drawing.Imaging.ImageUtils](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/549a0eca-43f9-1c6d-efb2-5a9966aab5d4.htm) class.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I had already implemented it myself using unsafe pointer manipulation, but this is probably the safer way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I recently read an article about this. I haven't tried it, because i need other rotations than 90/180/270, but it claims to be a fast way to rotate.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ImageRotationForCF.aspx

[edit]
damn, i didn't read correctly, you already found this.. sorry.